# R dplyr `group_by` seems not working to create a new value using `case_when`?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I am trying to create a new column in data  frame based on the groups `site` and conditions using `case_when`. However, my output seems to ignore my groups?

My example:

```
site     = c("a", "b", "b", "d", "d", "d", "e", "f", "g")
distance = c("PA", "PA", "5", "PA", "20", "5", "5", "20", "PA")
df <- data.frame(site, 
                 distance)
```

Apply conditions:

- if there is only PA by group        -> PA
- if there is PA and something else   -> unclear
- if there is something else (not PA) -> buffer

Script:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
  mutate(source = case_when(distance == "PA" ~ "PA",
                            any(c("PA") %in% distance) ~ "unclear",
                            TRUE ~ "buffer"))
```

My example seems to work well row-wise, but not taking into account groups?

Expected output by group `site`:

```
  site  distance source 
  <fct> <fct>    <chr>  
1 a     PA       PA     
2 b     PA       unclear    # not PA
3 b     5        unclear
4 d     PA       unclear    # not PA, as the group contains other values! 
5 d     20       unclear
6 d     5        unclear
7 e     5        buffer 
8 f     20       buffer 
9 g     PA       PA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the following conditions :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
  mutate(source = case_when(
                    #if there is only PA by group
                    all(distance == "PA") ~ "PA",
                    #PA + something else
                    any(distance == "PA") && any(distance != "PA") ~ "unclear",
                    #everything else
                    TRUE ~ "buffer")) 


#  site  distance source 
#  <fct> <fct>    <chr>  
#1 a     PA       PA     
#2 b     PA       unclear
#3 b     5        unclear
#4 d     PA       unclear
#5 d     20       unclear
#6 d     5        unclear
#7 e     5        buffer 
#8 f     20       buffer 
#9 g     PA       PA
```

Comment: You may skip `&& any(distance != "PA")` chunk because execution of `case_when` goes from first expression to last and this condition (`any(distance != "PA")`) is already took into account for 2nd expression.

Comment: Yes, that is true. It could allow making the query shorter and faster. Although, if data is not too big and speed is not really a factor I would still keep it in because it makes it clear what we are checking for.